# Show data from JSON using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following JSON:

```
var data = [{"datapresub":"08\/08\/2018","datasub":"08\/08\/2018","nomeComune":"ROMA","provincia":"RM"}]
```

I want to show the results for each value of the Json using jQuery. The problem is that this script show the results only for the object that have index zero.

Any solution?

I tried this:

```
function(data) {
                            var jsonData = JSON.parse(data),
                                filterData = jsonData,
                                i;
                            for (i = 0; i < filterData.length; i++ ) {
                                if(filterData[i]['datasub']) {
                                    $('.nome-comune').html(filterData[i]['nomeComune']);
                                    $('.provincia').html(filterData[i]['provincia']);
                                    $('.data-sub').html(filterData[i]['datasub']);
                                    resultsSub();
                                } else if(filterData[i]['datapresub'] && filterData[i]['datasub'] == 0) {
                                    $('.nome-comune').html(filterData[i]['nomeComune']);
                                    $('.provincia').html(filterData[i]['provincia']);
                                    $('.data-presub').html(filterData[i]['datapresub']);
                                    resultsPresub();
                                }

                            }


                        }
```

the Json data is passed from a PHP script that filter data coming from an API.

thanks

Comment: Show us what you have tried that isn't working for you

Comment: The `html()` method replaces any existing content in those elements. So every iteration of the loop will wipe out previous content. What is expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are data variable have more array? you count filterData.length. 
There are data show at table html use `append`.

```
var data = [{"datapresub":"08\/08\/2018","datasub":"08\/08\/2018","nomeComune":"ROMA","provincia":"RM"}];
    console.log(data);

    let filterData = data;
    let tr = '';
    for (i = 0; i < filterData.length; i++ ) {
      tr += '<tr>'+
          '<td>'+filterData[i].datapresub+'</td>'+
          '<td>'+filterData[i].datasub+'</td>'+
          '<td>'+filterData[i].nomeComune+'</td>'+
          '<td>'+filterData[i].provincia+'</td>'+
        '</tr>';       
    }
    $('#table_element').append(tr);
```

and add table element at your view page.

```
<table id="table_element" border=1></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following [json parse](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) function you can apply this to parse json string.

```js
   var data = JSON.parse('{"datapresub":"08\/08\/2018","datasub":"08\/08\/2018","nomeComune":"ROMA","provincia":"RM"}');
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data.datapresub + ", " + data.datasub + ", " + data.nomeComune + ", " + data.provincia;
```

```html
<h2>Create Object from JSON String</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>
```